# Redirect to root page if route doesnt exist in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

application_controller.rb

```
def index
 redirect_to root_url
end
```

routes.rb

```
match "*path" => "play#home", via: [:get, :post]
```

the issue i am facing is it redirects all routes to the root_url even if the route exist.

Any idea where I make a mistake.

Comment: Is that the last rout in routes.rb? It should be. As they match in order.

Comment: @AryeDovEidelman i had not put it in the end. Now it works fine. Is it possible to flash a messge that route doesnt exist and user is redirected to root_url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this line at bottom of your routes.rb

```
match "*path" => redirect("/")
```